# Get dropdown values from excel with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, excel, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to read the possible values that a cell in excel can takes which are determined by a dropdown list with nodeJS.

I tried some packages like [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) or [xlsx-populate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-populate) but I can't access to that possible values.

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dropdown list, then there is likely a list of valid values on the worksheet. Can you just read the values themselves, instead of reading the dropdown cell? For example, my `sample.xlsx` file has valid values in A1:A7. The dropdown itself is in C1. Here's the code:

```
var XLSX = require('xlsx');
var workbook = XLSX.readFile('sample.xlsx');
var worksheet = workbook.Sheets['Sheet1'];

//dropdown data is in A1:A7
var desired_cell;
for (var i=1; i <= 7; i++) {
  desired_cell = worksheet['A'+i];
  console.log(desired_cell.v);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
red
orange
yellow
green
blue
indigo
violet
```

Comment: The values aren't in the worksheet ;(, just in the dropdown. I had to use python instead of node :(